# Transmit Live Android Audio without SIP

Tags: android, audio, stream, sip, audio-recording

I am looking to transmit audio in realtime from an Android application I am working on to a server in a way similar to how a baby monitor functions (one way listening).

I created a test app that uses SIP to initiate a VOIP call between our client and server applications. The problem is that now I need a way to do this on non-SIP enabled devices. I have tried recording the audio from the device microphone into a buffer, then sending the buffer in chunks to the server through HTTP objects and re-assembling the audio for playback with poor results.

Does anyone have any suggestions for streaming realtime audio from an Android device to a server application for processing? SIP works so well, but I don't have time to implement a SIP stack on all of our non supported devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP/jingle (aka gtalk) is the usual alternative. There are C libraries as well as some support in java using the smack libraries. (The smack jingle support is old and doesn't work well, but IIRC someone is working on a new version)

Comment: Looking into this, thanks for the quick response I'll let you know how it turns out :-)

Comment: @JoshuaWitter Hi Joshua, how did this turn out for you? I am curious.

Comment: You might be interested in java bells, which i wrote since answering this question. IDK if it will work on android: https://github.com/bejayoharen/java-bells